# How can I add nodes to my GridPane without the program returning an InvocationTargetException?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm writing a small GUI program for playing Chess. I have stumbled upon the problem that I can't add any elements to **chessTable** without the program returning an **InvocationTargetExcepetion**. Here is my code:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    GridPane chessTable = new GridPane();
    chessTable.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("styles.css").toString());
    Box chessBox = new Box(112 , 94, 0);
    chessBox.getStyleClass().add("chess-box");
    for (int h = 0; h < 8; h++) {
        for (int w = 0; w < 8; w++) {
            GridPane.setConstraints(chessBox, w, h);
            chessTable.getChildren().add(chessBox);

        }
    }
    primaryStage.setTitle("ChessGame");
    primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
    Scene scene = new Scene(chessTable, 900, 750);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: What are your imports? You may be trying to add a swing box rather than a JavaFX box.

Comment: In the future, include the full [stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/). The `InvocationTargetException` should never be the root problem; look at the `Caused by:`s to see what's _really_ the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something along these lines(eg. I don't know where your "styles.css" resides ...) :

```
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        GridPane chessTable = new GridPane();
        chessTable.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/styles.css").toString());
        for (int h = 0; h < 8; h++) {
            for (int w = 0; w < 8; w++) {
                Box chessBox = new Box(112, 94, 0);
                chessBox.getStyleClass().add("chess-box");
                GridPane.setConstraints(chessBox, w, h);
                chessTable.getChildren().add(chessBox);

            }
        }
```

Note that it creates a new Box for every cell in oposite to your code, that tries to put the same box in different cells at the same time(can only add it once).